# SQL: how to search in two different tables, merging the results?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, search

This is a wordpress database and I have 2 tables of interest: posts and postmeta. What I want to do is to get $term(searched by users) and use this variable on the SQL search.

The tables I want to search if there is a match are meta_value(if meta_key is albumYear), post_content and post_title.

The problem is that meta_value is in a different table than the others, but its table postmeta has post_id, which is the same id that posts.ID. This makes possible to know that some meta value belongs to some post.

I tried the following code and I hope I made it clear what I need so I can get help from people here. I really need help on this and I couldn't find the answer on google or here. Thanks in advance.

```
$query_sql = "
    SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    ,
     (SELECT *
     FROM $wpdb->posts
     WHERE NOT wpdb->posts.post_status = 'inherit'
     AND (wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' OR wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post')
     AND (wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%".$term."%' OR wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$term."%')
     ORDER BY wpdb->posts.post_title ASC) x
     WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'albumYear'
";

$query_result = $wpdb->get_results($query_sql, OBJECT);
```

Sample of the SQL structure:

```
1.wp_posts
1.1 ID, post_type, post_content, post_status, post_name, post_title etc

2.wp_postmeta
2.1 post_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

So, I need to search matches for $term in meta_value(when meta_key is X), post_content, post_name etc. But also I need to identify the Post im searching and return all of its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is just a join of two tables.

Sorry, don't have WP available atm, so can't check it, but should like something like that:

```
$query_sql = "
  SELECT 
    post_id, meta_key, meta_value,
    $wpdb->posts.*
  FROM $wpdb->posts
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
  WHERE NOT wpdb->posts.post_status = 'inherit'
    AND (wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' OR wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post')
    AND (wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%".$term."%' OR 
         wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR 
         $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$term."%')
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'albumYear'
  ORDER BY wpdb->posts.post_title ASC
";
```

Add your checks and query fields list if you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as expected. I think it's because meta_key and meta_value are not being queried from $wpdb->postmeta . How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to get it as `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key` and `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value`?

Comment: Ok i made it kinda work, but it cant find meta_value inside the array results... please look at it: LINK EDITED - im organizing the results so you can help me better.

Comment: From what I understood, it turned the 1 post result into four, each one with one meta_value in it(there are 4 meta_values, each one with a different meta_key attached to the post_id) Here is the result: http://pastebin.com/yitDU0jj

Comment: I made it work. Is it very complicated to make the search possible for more than one word? I mean, if I search X, it will find it. But if I search X Y (both words are in the post) it won't find it. :S

Comment: This query simple returns you several rows, thats matched. So you getting array of results. You need to iterate it and do what you need with it.

Regarding search you are limiting table query with some rules:
`$wpdb->post_type = 'page'` - you say that you need all results that have column `post_type` equals literal `page`.
You can further limit query or add more matches.
When you say `AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value like '%".$term."%'` - you looking for rows that both of post_type page and also match mask "*search_term*" (% - have same meaning as asterisk in regular masks).

Comment: So if your search term consist of two words `hello there`, you actually will be looking for this two words together somewhere in text exactly as u've wrote it.
If you want to match any of this words or two but separately, you have to split your string in few terms and look for each one separetly.
Also if you want case insensetive matching you should lower or upper both part of the search request.

Well, its getting a bit out of Q&A scope, you should read some tutorial about sql queries.

Comment: Thanks for everything Nagh. I just have one more question about the results. I am getting repeated results, but only when i search things that are in .posts, not in .postmeta, is that possible that its something wrong with the code? (+1 result for each meta_key on postmeta that matches the ID of the post)

Comment: sure. query results are here: http://pastebin.com/eyDCCqMW
and the value of $term is "of"

Comment: Ok, we have here 1 to many relationship, means 1 row from post can match many rows from meta.
Thats why you getting double records, its ain't double, meta_value always different, so rows ain't equal.
Now you need to decide how you want to handle it, that will depend on what you want to do with this data.
If everything you need is just return post_id and its content, then you need to select only this columns and use DISTINCT to remove duplicates.

Comment: hm I understand it now. I think the best way to achieve the results matching meta_values is to tell left join to get matching post_id row and tell it to behave as column, Ex.: meta_key(col) albumYear(value) (if I could tell albumYear to be a column) and meta_value(col) value(value) and then tell value(row from meta_value) to be its content. and then do this to every meta_key I need(I must be able to change the code if I add more meta_key)

Comment: Not sure if u getting it right,so just a little sample:
Lets say, you are looking for `2012` keyword in posts, and also in  meta_value for meta_key albumYear, as result u wanna get posts that matched this criteria.
`SELECT DISTINCT
    $wpdb->posts.post_id, $wpdb->posts.post_content
  FROM $wpdb->posts
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
  WHERE wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%".$term."%' OR 
        ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$term."%'
         AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'albumYear')`

This way you will get post id and its content as result.

Comment: actually that didnt return any results.

Comment: I did it! SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%".$term."%' OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%".$term."%' OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$term."%' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'albumYear') OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$term."%' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'band')) I made it work with this code! Thanks a lot Nagh for your huge patience with me.